# Complicated conditional SQL query

Tags: ms-access, mysql

I'm not even sure if it's possible but I need it for my Access database. So I have following db structure :

[image]
<sub>(source: [virtualdesign.pl](http://images.virtualdesign.pl/images/25480Drawing1.jpg))</sub>

Now I need to perform a query that takes category_id from my product and do the magic :
- let's say product belongs to console (`category_id` is in table Console)
- from console_types take `type_id`, where `category_id == category_id`
- but if product belongs to `console_game` (`category_id` is in table `console_game`)
- from `console_game` take `game_cat_id`, where `category_id == category_id`

I'm not sure if mysql is capable of such thing. If not I really have a problem. Maybe there is a way to split this into 2,3 separate queries ?

EDIT :

I've found something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT type_id FROM console WHERE category_id='category_id')`. Maybe this will be helpful ?

Comment: So just to get it clear - the second and fourth bullet points are the results you want to retrieve as one result set?

I'd also look at condensing the tables that hold categories into perhaps one table which would have ID, Parent ID, Category Name. If possible.

Comment: no no, separate. If product is of console do ... , else do ... . Unfortunately my base is already built and full of products :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the case statement to do a select like:

```
Select Case (expression)
Case option1
    statement1
Case option2
    statement2
```

[Example Access case statement](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/select-case-statement.html)

Case statements work in MySql, Sql Server etc. (Syntax varies between implementations).

Comment: so FROM product SELECT category_ID CASE WHEN ... - but how to check if category_id is in console, console_game or accessory ? Use some IF's ?

Comment: like : IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT type_id FROM console WHERE category_id='category_id') ?

Comment: The cited example is for VBA. CASE SELECT is not valid Jet/ACE SQL. Alternatives are Choose() and Switch() and nested IIf(), but in general, any over-complex use of that suggests you're storing data in your SQL statement and ought to use a table that you can join, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing three sub queries and use [UNION ALL](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php) to merge them.